# I Get A Wierd Error When Attempting To Paste in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I recently got Visual Studio 2013 and upgraded it to the latest versions.  I created an MVC 5 website application and every time I attempt to paste content into the _Layout.cshtml page, I get this weird error:

[image]

Here's the specs of my VS instance:

[image]

As you can tell, this is excruciatingly apprehensive.  Please help!

Comment: I already closed Visual Studio and reopened it and this error still happens...

Comment: My guess is that you either have a broken addin that you then need to uninstall or else you need to reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  My login credentials to my VS account changed somehow.  I had to reset my password to my VS login and my credentials to the app registered again.  Works fine now.